# Selecting 'highest' X rows without sorting

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization

I've got a table with huge amount of data. Lets say 10GB of lines, containing bunch of crap. I need to select for example X rows (X is usually below 10) with highest `amount` column.

Is there any way how to do it without sorting the whole table? Sorting this amount of data is extremely time-expensive, I'd be OK with one scan through the whole table and selecting X highest values, and letting the rest untouched. I'm using SQL Server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an index on `amount` then SQL Server can select the `top 10` from that and do bookmark lookups to retrieve the missing columns.

Comment: whoa. Thanks. I didn't realized the difference in execution plan between Top N Sort and Sort, adding index helped too.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP 10 Amount FROM myTable ORDER BY Amount DESC
```

if it is indexed, the query optimizer should use the index.
If not, I do no see how one could avoid scanning the whole thing...

Wether an index is usefull or not depends on how often you do that search.
You could also consider putting that query into an **indexed view**. I think this will give you the best benefit/cost ration.

Comment: Thanks. Pity I cannot accept both answers, but Martin was first.

Comment: If the timings are really long, I would be curious about what's more efficient: an index or an indexed view.

Comment: Indexed views can be used only in 'better' versions of SQL server, thus are unusable for me :-(